# Preg replace URL - attach affiliate ID

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

Ebay links should be replaced with the affiliate ID. Therefore I use preg replace. It works when there is only 1 URL in the $message string. When there are more then 1 URL´s in the $message string, only the first URL is working. The other URLs are not replaced.

```
$message = preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="(http:\/\/(cgi|www).ebay.*(=|\/)([0-9]{12,})[=\?\/]?[^"]*)"[^<]*<\/a>/Uis', '<a onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" href="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/707-53477-19255-0/1?ff3=4&pub=3454345446&toolid=10001&campid=234342343&customid=&mpre=$2" title="Ebay Article: $5" target="_blank">http://www.ebay.com/itm/$5</a><img style="text-decoration:none;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;" src="http://rover.ebay.com/roverimp/1/707-53477-19255-0/1?ff3=4&pub=3454345446&toolid=10043&campid=345445454&customid=&mpt=[CACHEBUSTER]">', $message);
```

I found out, when I change the

```
{12,}
```

to

```
{0,}
```

all URL´s are replaced, but then is the $5 empty. But I need this $5 in the URL.

Someone have a idea?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{0,}` that is equal to `*`, you make this whole number optional, and the previous greedy sub-expression - `.*` - eats up the most of your input string.

Use `+` (or `{1,}`).

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply. When I use "+" no URL is replaced. When I use {1,} the first and the last one are replaced but not the one in the middle. Thank you for more help.

Comment: For more help, please provide a sample input string with the desired output.